# How do I import a certificate chain and it's certificate into a java keystore?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I have a wilcard certificate along with a certificate chain and private key.
How do I import that into my java keystore?

certificate chain
*.whatever.com - certificate
private key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://cunning.sharp.fm/2008/06/importing_private_keys_into_a.html) -

You have to convert your to a PKCS12 certificate to import it with a command similar to the following.

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore my-keystore.jks -srckeystore cert-and-key.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass cert-and-key-password -alias 1
```

To convert from [PEM to PKCS12](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html) use the following command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Comment: do u know how can i do it programmatically?